# How do I debug a problem with vs 2017 intellisense going very slow but only on certain files

Tags: visual-studio-2017, intellisense

Using vs 2017, I've got a solution with 20 projects in it, all C++, none of them that big.

On certain files in one project, intellisense goes extremely slow, or doesn't work at all.
When I select a class member variable name, it doesn't get highlighted. When I git f12, it will pop up the "Intellisense operation in progress..." dialog for 4-5 seconds and will eventually give me a reference in the header and the cpp file for the member variable, whereas usually, it will just go to one of them and not give me a list.

All other cpp and header files work fine, quick response and I get matching-variable highlighting.

The errors pane shows no errors from intellisense or the build. I have no idea what makes these few cpp files special that they don't work.

I've tried removing the project and adding it back, I've tried deleting the .vs directory.

I'm not sure what else to try.

Anybody have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you run any add-ins, such as ReSharper? Beyond that, if you've not updated Visual Studio to a recent or to the latest version, doing so might help. There were some intellisense issues in earlier VS 2017 versions, so it depends how dated your installation is.

Comment: I'll defer to others more familiar with C++ within VS (I'm a C# programmer, primarily), but it might trigger some ideas for you if you missed the various IntelliSense settings available in Tools | Options | Text Editor | C/C++ | Advanced. I would also try to disable IntelliSense there, then re-enable it, just to see if that triggers a process not fixed by deleting the .vs folder...

Comment: I don't use resharper, I hear it's wonderful except that it makes everything not work. I'll try the disabling and restarting there, thanks.